# Mockito with Java async->sync converter

Tags: java, asynchronous, mockito

I have an async method I am converting to a sync method using a countdown latch. I'm struggling with writing a unit test without using mockito's timeout function. I can't work out how to get the verify method to wait for the async method call:

```
public interface SyncExchangeService {
    boolean placeOrder(Order order);
}
public interface ExchangeService {
    void placeOrder(Order order, OrderCallback orderResponseCallback);
}

public interface OrderCallback {
    public void onSuccess();
    public void onFailure();
}



public class SyncExchangeServiceAdapter implements SyncExchangeService {
    private ExchangeService exchangeService;

    public SyncExchangeServiceAdapter(ExchangeService exchangeService) {
        this.exchangeService = exchangeService;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean placeOrder(Order order) {

        final CountDownLatch countdownLatch=new CountDownLatch(1);
        final AtomicBoolean result=new AtomicBoolean();
        exchangeService.placeOrder(order, new OrderCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                result.set(true);
                countdownLatch.countDown();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(String rejectReason) {
                result.set(false);
                countdownLatch.countDown();
            }
        });
        try {
            countdownLatch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return result.get();
    }
}


public class SyncExchangeServiceAdapterTest {
    private ExchangeService mockExchange=mock(ExchangeService.class);
    private SyncExchangeServiceAdapter adapter=new SyncExchangeServiceAdapter(mockExchange);
    private Boolean response;
    private ArgumentCaptor<Boolean> callback=CaptorArgumentCaptor.forClass(OrderCallback.class);
    private CountDownLatch latch=new CountDownLatch(1);


    @Test
    public void testPlaceOrderWithSuccess() throws Exception {
        final Order order=mock(Order.class);
         Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                response=adapter.placeOrder(order);
                latch.countDown();
            }
        });
            verify(mockExchange,timeout(10) ).placeOrder(eq(order), callbackCaptor.capture());
//the timeout method is not really recommended and could also fail randomly if the thread takes more than 10ms


        callbackCaptor.getValue().onSuccess();
        latch.await(1000,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            assertEquals(true,response);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For these kinds of tests I like to use a little library called [awaitility](http://code.google.com/p/awaitility/). You can do it yourself with a countdown latch, but as you have seen you have to hack up your test with a machete to make that work.

In this test you should call verify after you have awaited the latch.

Another problem in your code is the `private Boolean response`. Since you're changing it in another thread you should make that an `AtomicBoolean` or at least declare it `volatile`.

Comment: +1 for awaitility.  I had never heard of it, but it looks quite useful.

Answer (score -1):

i'm not sure i understand you correctly. if you want to tests that one thread waits indefinitely until other thread does something then i would say you can't do it. because that means you are asking if the program terminates. instead you can do two things.

1. do regular concurrent tests (by definition it's random and don't give you certainty that the code is correct). you create complex test with two threads that uses locks and simulates the service and use yeld() method. in critical sections you can test if there is no incorrect order. of course you have to run it many times so it will take you more than 10ms
2. assume that CountDownLatch works correctly, mock it and check if its functions are called in the right order

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are getting at..I'm looking for a deterministic way of testing the class above. i.e. it will ALWAYS yield the same result regardless of whether you run it once or a million times. At the moment there is a race condition so it could fail.

Comment: Also without restructuring the class you cannot mock CountDownLatch as its not being passed in as a dependency.

Comment: that is my point. you simply can't test multi-threaded code in a deterministic way to say: 'it is correct'. you can't test if one thread waits until another [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem]. and of course you can mock countDownLatch, see powermock and whitebox

Comment: You can't mock it as its not exposed. I would have to pass in a CountDownLatch factory.

Comment: it is exposed (package scope) but unfortunately is also final. if you want/need it to be final, create another package scoped constructor and pass it as a parameter

Comment: Its not exposed...its a local variable.

Comment: you're right, my bad. sorry. in that case i would try to refactor the code and pass that latch (or even more complex synchronization object) to OrderCallback. it could be helpful to create helper method placeOrder(Order, CoundownLatch)